# Accessing Traefik UI webpage

Tags: docker, proxy, dns, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm trying to deploy traefik on docker swarm using this .yml file that I found on https://dockerswarm.rocks/traefik/:

```
> version: '3.3'
> 
> services:
> 
>   traefik:
>     # Use the latest v2.2.x Traefik image available
>     image: traefik:v2.2
>     ports:
>       # Listen on port 80, default for HTTP, necessary to redirect to HTTPS
>       - 80:80
>       # Listen on port 443, default for HTTPS
>       - 443:443
>     deploy:
>       placement:
>         constraints:
>           # Make the traefik service run only on the node with this label
>           # as the node with it has the volume for the certificates
>           - node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates == true
>       labels:
>         # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
>         - traefik.enable=true
>         # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
>         - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
>         # Use the custom label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
>         # This public Traefik will only use services with this label
>         # That way you can add other internal Traefik instances per stack if needed
>         - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
>         # admin-auth middleware with HTTP Basic auth
>         # Using the environment variables USERNAME and HASHED_PASSWORD
>         - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users=${USERNAME?Variable
> not set}:${HASHED_PASSWORD?Variable not set}
>         # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
>         # It can be re-used by other stacks in other Docker Compose files
>         - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
>         - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
>         # traefik-http set up only to use the middleware to redirect to https
>         # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable
> not set}`)
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect
>         # traefik-https the actual router using HTTPS
>         # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable
> not set}`)
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true
>         # Use the special Traefik service api@internal with the web UI/Dashboard
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal
>         # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver created below
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le
>         # Enable HTTP Basic auth, using the middleware created above
>         - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth
>         # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
>         - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
>     volumes:
>       # Add Docker as a mounted volume, so that Traefik can read the labels of other services
>       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
>       # Mount the volume to store the certificates
>       - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
>     command:
>       # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
>       - --providers.docker
>       # Add a constraint to only use services with the label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
>       - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `traefik-public`)
>       # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
>       - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
>       # Enable Docker Swarm mode
>       - --providers.docker.swarmmode
>       # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on port 80
>       - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
>       # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on port 443
>       - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
>       # Create the certificate resolver "le" for Let's Encrypt, uses the environment variable EMAIL
>       - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${EMAIL?Variable not set}
>       # Store the Let's Encrypt certificates in the mounted volume
>       - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
>       # Use the TLS Challenge for Let's Encrypt
>       - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
>       # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
>       - --accesslog
>       # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
>       - --log
>       # Enable the Dashboard and API
>       - --api
>     networks:
>       # Use the public network created to be shared between Traefik and
>       # any other service that needs to be publicly available with HTTPS
>       - traefik-public
> 
> volumes:   # Create a volume to store the certificates, there is a
> constraint to make sure   # Traefik is always deployed to the same
> Docker node with the same volume containing   # the HTTPS certificates
> traefik-public-certificates:
> 
> networks:   # Use the previously created public network
> "traefik-public", shared with other   # services that need to be
> publicly available via this Traefik   traefik-public:
>     external: true
```

I've tried the external ip address of my vm but I'm getting a 404 error page not found.
Checking the logs, I found that there was a DNS error

> msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains
> "traefik.domain.com": unable to generate a certificate for the domains
> [traefik.domain.com]: error: one or more domains had a
> problem:\n[traefik.domain.com] acme: error: 400 ::
> urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A
> for traefik.domain.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain,
> url: \n" providerName=le.acme routerName=traefik-public-https@docker
> rule="Host(`traefik.domain.com`)"

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

LetsEncrypt is a public cloud service that issues certificates to web sites for free.

It uses a DNS challenge protocol to ensure that certificates are not issued to man in the middle sites - servers need to be able to prove their ownwership of the domain by answering a DNS challenge. This is done by LetEncrypt doing a callback to the domain passing a token (for the web challenge).
Obviously this means that LetsEncrypt can only be used for real public DNS entries that you own, that are pointing at your swarm so that Traefik can handle the challenge.

If you are trying to do this with an on-prem setup with a private domain, then you can use something like Step-CA - which provides an ACME compliant CA that can be installed on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining well known internet DNS servers in my traefik.yml file

```
certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:    
      email: email@domain.com
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "8.8.8.8:53"
          - "9.9.9.9:53"
```